# Output value from array

Tags: php, printing

```
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM x WHERE id='{$variable}' GROUP BY id"));
    return $rows;
```

When i do a print_r($rows), i get an output which looks like this:

```
Array ( [COUNT(*)] => 2 )
```

What i want is the '2', so i tried

```
print $rows[0];
```

which didn't work. I tried:

```
print $rows[COUNT(*)];
```

which didn't work either...

Any ideas?

Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add alias using `AS` keyword. I given the name as `total`

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM x WHERE id='{$variable}' GROUP BY id"
```

Now you can get it `print $rows['total'];`

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your SQL statement to:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total .......
```

And now you can access it with `total` keyword:

```
print $rows['total'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a column alias for the `COUNT()`.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS numrows FROM x WHERE id='{$variable}' GROUP BY id"));
if ($result) {
   $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   echo $rows['numrows'];  
}
```

**Note about error handling and style:  ** I have refactored your code to store the result resource in`$result` rather than passing it directly to `mysql_fetch_assoc()`.  If your query fails for any reason but you pass the resource directly to a fetch call, you will get errors.

Answer (score 0):

Please below code

```
$rows = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM x WHERE id='{$variable}' GROUP BY id"));
    return $rows;
```

This will work for you.

If you use `mysql_fetch_array` then result set come in 2 type one as field name and another as array index 0,1,.... and so on

This will help you

Answer (score 0):

If you need complex query (for example select article and count of comments for it) I'd use [`AS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) as Click suggested, based on those lines from manual:

> A select_expr can be given an alias using AS alias_name. The alias is
>   used as the expression's column name and can be used in GROUP BY,
>   ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses. For example:
>
> SELECT CONCAT(last_name,', ',first_name) AS full_name   FROM mytable
>   ORDER BY full_name;

However you need only one value you should use [`mysql_fetch_row()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) which always returns numeric array:

> Returns an numerical array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or FALSE if there are no more rows.

So you would have:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS numrows FROM x WHERE id='{$variable}' GROUP BY id"));
$row = mysql_fetch_row( $result);
print_r( $row); // array( 0 => 2);
echo $row[0]; //2
```

Or you could use [`mysql_fetch_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php) which is defined as:

> Retrieves the contents of one cell from a MySQL result set.

And usage would simply be:

```
echo mysql_fetch_result( $result, 0, 0); // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getOne($sql) {
  $res = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$sql);
  if (!res) return FALSE;
  $row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
  return $row[0];
}

$count = getOne("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM x WHERE id='{$variable}' GROUP BY id");
```

though to use this code one have to understand what user defined function is.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM x WHERE id='{$variable}' GROUP BY id"), 0, 0);
```