# SELECT Count php/sql

Tags: php, mysql, count

I am trying to store a mysql value into a php variable. I have the following query which I know works. However, I the value for $count is always 0. Can someone explain what I need to do to get the count value? The count should be the count of x's w here name_x=.$id.

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(name_x) FROM Status where name_x=.$id.";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$count = $result;
```

Comment: You want to retrieve the results using `mysql_result` on `$result`. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php

Comment: the problem is in `COUNT(x)`.. just use `COUNT(*)`. Also I believe id is INT...

Comment: @rjz: when I try to set $count = mysql_result($result,0), I don't get back any values for count.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Output value from array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532789/output-value-from-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is first letter in table name is really  capital. Please check it first.

or Try :

```
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as totalno FROM Status where name_x=".$id;
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($data=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $count = $data['totalno'];
    }
echo $count;
```

Comment: Yes, the first label in the table is really capital. I tried your suggestion to no avail and I even tried the following and it gave the error EXPECTS PARAMETER 1 TO BE RESOURCE, BOOLEAN GIVEN:$query = "SELECT name_x FROM Status where name_x=.$id.";
 $result = mysql_query($query);
 $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

Comment: EXPECTS PARAMETER 1 TO BE RESOURCE, BOOLEAN GIVEN: I am sure query is not ok. check fields & table  name and make sure u are connected to correct database.

Comment: Thank you Teez, I saw the error, I had the .$id in quotes. Sorry for all of the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Status` where `name_x`= $id";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$count = $row[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

please try it

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Status where name_x=$id";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$count = mysql_result($result, 0);
```

Comment: When I try the Select command in mysql, I get back a result; however, in the php file, I don't get anything back. I have used the * and that doesn't solve the problem either.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing single quotes around $id.  Should be 
    name_x = '" . $id . "'";