# How to correctly use SQL count in my situation

Tags: php, sql, pdo, count

On my website, I have implemented a reply system, or a "mention" system and now I want to let the user know when they have a new mention without having to go to the mentions page and manually checking. On my website, I have a sidebar with navigation links, I'd like to have the mentions link say something like "Mentions(2)" where 2 is however many new mentions you have.

So the only problem I am having is returning the count of the number of rows that this SQL query returns.

Using this I get "Mentions(Array)", but how would I retrieve the number of how many rows is being selected?

```
$getMentions = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(seen) AS readMentions FROM mentions WHERE mentioned = :username AND seen = 0");

$getMentions->execute(array(':username' => $_SESSION['USER']));

$mentions = $getMentions->fetch();

echo "<li><a href='../mentions.php'>Mentions (".$mentions.")</a></li>";
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$mentions['readMentions']`? `fetch()` returns an array.

Comment: Here is the answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543655/select-count-php-sql

Answer (score 1):

[`fetch`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) returns an array indexed, by default, by both column name and a zero based index with the results of the row. So instead of `echo`ing `$mentions`, you should be `echo`ing `$mentions['readMentions']` or `$mentions[0]`.